# Flutter driver: how to pass json mock to test?

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, integration, ui-automation

can anyone please help. I test flutter app and I want it to change after I tap on spamOffer variable. How can I do this?

```html
static Future<void> markAsSpamOffer(FlutterDriver driver) async {
    final deleteOffer = find.byValueKey(ProjectsIds.deleteOffer);
    final spamOffer = find.byValueKey(ProjectsIds.spamOffer);

   
    await driver.waitFor(deleteOffer).then((_) => driver.tap(deleteOffer));
    await driver.waitFor(spamOffer).then((_) => driver.tap(spamOffer));
```